# Crafting a Subquery-able UNION ALL based on the results of a query

Tags: mariadb, common-table-expression, procedure, dynamicquery, recursive-cte

## Data

I have a couple of tables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE cycles (
  `cycle` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cycle_type` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` date DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rsvn (
  `str` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `cycles` (`cycle`, `cycle_type`, `start`, `end`) values
('202013', 'a', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-31'),
('202013', 'b', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-31'),
('202101', 'a', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-31'),
('202101', 'b', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-31'),
('202102', 'a', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-28'),
('202102', 'b', '2021-02-01', '2021-02-28'),
('202103', 'a', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-28'),
('202103', 'b', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-28');

INSERT INTO `rsvn` (str, start_date, end_date) values
('STR01367', '2020-12-07', '2020-06-21'),
('STR00759', '2020-12-07', '2021-04-25'),
('STR01367', '2021-01-04', '2021-09-12'),
('STR01367', '2021-06-21', '2022-02-27');
```

## Desired Results

For any given cycle, I want to count the number of occurrences of str across cycles. So between cycle 2108 - 2108 (one cycle), I see:

| str | count |
| --- | --- |
| STR01367 | 1 |
| STR00759 | 1 |

And from between 2108 - 2109 (two cycles) I see:

| str | count |
| --- | --- |
| STR01367 | 2 |
| STR00759 | 1 |

## What I've tried

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically obtain those results. I don't see any options outside a UNION ALL query (one query for each cycles), so I tried writing a PROCEDURE. However, that didn't work because I want to do post-processing on the query results, and I don't believe you can use the results of a PROCEDURE in a CTE or subquery.

My PROCEDURE (works, can't include results in a subquery like `SELECT * FROM call count_cycles` (?)):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `count_cycles`(start_cycle CHAR(6), end_cycle CHAR(6))
BEGIN
    SET @cycles := (
        SELECT CONCAT('WITH installed_cycles_count AS (',
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                CONCAT('
        SELECT rsvn.str, 1 AS installed_cycles
        FROM rsvn
        WHERE "', `cy`.`start`, '" BETWEEN rsvn.start_date AND COALESCE(rsvn.end_date, "9999-01-01")
           OR "', `cy`.`end`, '" BETWEEN rsvn.start_date AND COALESCE(rsvn.end_date, "9999-01-01")
        GROUP BY rsvn.str
    '
                )
                 SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
            ),
    ')

    SELECT
             store.chain AS "Chain"
            ,store.division AS "Division"
            ,dividers_store AS "Store"
            ,SUM(installed_cycles) AS "Installed Cycles"
    FROM installed_cycles_count r
    LEFT JOIN store ON store.name = r.dividers_store
    GROUP BY dividers_store
    ORDER BY chain, division, dividers_store, installed_cycles'
        )
        FROM cycles `cy`
        WHERE `cy`.`cycle_type` = 'Ad Cycle'
            AND `cy`.`cycle` >= CONCAT('20', RIGHT(start_cycle, 4))
            AND `cy`.`cycle` <= CONCAT('20', RIGHT(end_cycle, 4))
        GROUP BY `cy`.`cycle_type`
    );

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE @cycles;
END
```

Alternatively, I attempted to use a recursive query to obtain my results by incrementing my cycle. This gave me the cycles I wanted:

```
WITH RECURSIVE xyz AS (
    SELECT cy.`cycle`, cy.`start`, cy.`end`
    FROM cycles cy
    WHERE cycle_type = 'Ad Cycle'
    AND `cycle` = '202101'

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT cy.`cycle`, cy.`start`, cy.`end`
    FROM xyz
    JOIN cycles cy
        ON cy.`cycle` = increment_cycle(xyz.`cycle`, 1)
        AND cy.`cycle_type` = 'Ad Cycle'
    WHERE cy.`cycle` <= '202110'
)
SELECT * FROM xyz;
```

But I can't get it working when I add in the reservations table:
*infinite loop?*

```
WITH RECURSIVE xyz AS (
    SELECT cy.`cycle`, 'dr.dividers_store', 1 AS installed_cycles
    FROM cycles cy
    LEFT JOIN rsvn dr
        ON cy.`start` BETWEEN dr.start_date AND COALESCE(dr.end_date, "9999-01-01")
            OR cy.`end` BETWEEN dr.start_date AND COALESCE(dr.end_date, "9999-01-01")
    WHERE cy.`cycle_type` = 'Ad Cycle'
        AND cy.`cycle` = '202101'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cy.`cycle`, 'dr.dividers_store', 1 AS installed_cycles
    FROM xyz
    JOIN cycles cy
        ON cy.`cycle` = increment_cycle(xyz.`cycle`, 1)
        AND cy.`cycle_type` = 'Ad Cycle'
    LEFT JOIN rsvn dr
        ON cy.`start` BETWEEN dr.start_date AND COALESCE(dr.end_date, "9999-01-01")
            OR cy.`end` BETWEEN dr.start_date AND COALESCE(dr.end_date, "9999-01-01")
    WHERE cy.`cycle` <= '202102'
)
SELECT * FROM xyz
```

What options do I have to get the results I need, in such a way that I can use them in a CTE or subquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results I am looking for are easily obtained via a two-stage grouping. Something like this:

```
WITH sbc AS (
    SELECT cy.`cycle`, dr.str, 1 AS 'count'
    FROM cycles cy
    LEFT JOIN rsvn dr
        ON cy.`start` BETWEEN dr.start_date AND dr.end_date
            OR cy.`end` BETWEEN dr.start_date AND dr.end_date
    WHERE cy.`cycle_type` = 'Ad Cycle'
        AND cy.`cycle` BETWEEN '202201' AND '202205'
    GROUP BY cy.`cycle`, dr.str
    ORDER BY dr.str, cy.`cycle`
)
SELECT `cycle`, str, SUM(`count`) as `count`
FROM sbc
GROUP BY str
```

The CTE produces one result per rsvn per cycle. Afterwards all that is needed is to group by store and count the number of occurrences.

Besides being simpler, I suspect that this query is faster than the union concept I was stuck on when I asked the question, since among other things the server does not need to perform a union on multiple grouping queries. However, I do not understand how MariaDB optimizes such queries, and while I am curious I don't have the time to run benchmarks to find out.